# Informatica - Concatenate all rows of 1 column to a single value

Tags: sql, informatica

I am looking to convert all values from 1 columns to one single value in Informatica.

```
     Col1
Row1 A
Row2 B
Row3 C
Row4 D
```

To

```
     Col 1        
Row1 A,B,C,D
```

I have the the input available from an expression.
Thank you!

Comment: What's your dbms

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the title. This is being done on Informatica

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do it using a variable port in Expression transformation.

E.g.

```
in_Col1
v_Row1 := iif(isnull(v_Row1), in_Col1, v_Row1||','||in_Col1)
o_Row1 := v_Row1
```

After the Expression transformation, use an Aggregator transformation to pass only the last row which will have the concatenated value.

I have not tested it. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This looks like it should work. I implemented the following after your answer:
    `v_store = iif(isnull(v_store), o_input, v_store||','||o_input)`

.... It gives me output as just numbers

Comment: Why not calculate straight in the aggregator which allows expressions... saves a transformation... less port connections to go wrong

Comment: Hey @Samik, thanks for your answer. It was pretty close to what I needed.