# Informatica - combine rows according to source

Tags: sql, informatica

I have an input as shown in the table, which is rows coming from different sources( I don't know how many there might be). 
I want to reach the final table, as shown, which combines all the rows from each source.
Thanks for your help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try with unpivot

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: The input table I mentioned above is an output of expression in Informatica @D-Shih

Comment: @shrek could you expand more on unpivot could be implemented in my example?

Comment: Did the solution not work that I provided in your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274195/informatica-concatenate-all-rows-of-1-column-to-a-single-value/51276688?noredirect=1#comment89533170_51276688

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Informatica - Concatenate all rows of 1 column to a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274195/informatica-concatenate-all-rows-of-1-column-to-a-single-value)

Comment: Hey @Samik, thank you for your reply. My use case had changed so I posted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy - use an aggregator with two variable fields, first vOut calculated to be 
    IIf(vSource = Source,  vOut || "," || Column, Column)

Followed by vSource calculated as
    Source

Grouped by Source.

...note it will only work if vSource is lower in the port order than vOut